# Redirect after forum log-in when site_url is protocol agnostic

Tags: login, config, forum, domain

I have stumbled across an issue with the forum module whereby if you have a site_url specified in config as protocol agnostic, i.e. minus http: or https: then the redirect after forum log-in always returns you to the site home page.

My site_url value is set as "//www.example.com"
My Forum URL is set as "/forums/"

When the redirect after log-in through the forum templates occurs I get sent to:

http://www.example.com/www.example.com/forums

Any thoughts? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this eventually by adding the following to my config:

```
if (false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/forums')) {
    $config['site_url'] = 'https:'.$config['site_url'];
}
```

This forces the requests for the forums module to use absolute protocol and this negates the log-in redirect issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same settings as you have except for the http:// protocol being there.

It works pretty well for me, when I log in from the forums it takes me to the forum home.

[image]

Comment: That's the crux of my issue... if you want the protocol to be universal then the log-in redirect for the forum fails. :/